# Declaring this double without being able to alter the .hpp file

Tags: c++

I've finished writing this library simulator, but i'm just a bit confused with this basic question. I have to implement this "overdue fee" which is 10 cents, but i'm not allowed to alter the .hpp files the prof has provided me. **If I declare DAILY_FINE as a static const double in my cpp file, will I get an error?**

sorry for the basic question!

Header:

```
//Library.hpp
#ifndef LIBRARY_HPP
#define LIBRARY_HPP
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Patron.hpp"

class Library {

private:
   std::vector<Book*> holdings;
   std::vector<Patron*> members;
   int currentDate;

public:
   Library();
   void addBook(Book*);
   void addPatron(Patron*);
   std::string checkOutBook(std::string pID, std::string bID);
   std::string returnBook(std::string bID);
   std::string requestBook(std::string pID, std::string bID);
   std::string payFine(std::string pID, double payment);
   void incrementCurrentDate();
   Patron* getPatron(std::string pID);
   Book* getBook(std::string bID);
};
#endif
```

cpp (the part i'm concerned with)

```
    /******************************************
** Description: incrementCurrentDate function
*******************************************/
void Library::incrementCurrentDate() {
   currentDate++;
   cout < "Current Date has been changed from " << currentDate-1
   << " to " << currentDate << endl;
   int i=0;
   for (i=0; i<members.size(); i++) {
      vector<Book*> checkedOut = members[i].getCheckedOutBooks();
      if (!checkedOut.empty()) {
         for (int x=0; x<checkedOut.size(); x++) {
            int length = (currentDate - (*checkedOut[x]).getDateCheckedOut());
            if (length>21) {
               cout << " (" << (*checkedOut[x].getTitle() << " is overdue)" << endl;
               members[i].amendFine(DAILY_FINE); //Where would I declare DAILY_FINE as .10?
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `If I declare DAILY_FINE as a static const double in my cpp file, will I get an error?` Did you try it?

Comment: Also, everywhere you have `(*foo).bar()`, you should write `foo->bar()`.

Comment: ah, it works! and thanks for the heads up for the (*foo).bar() bit, but i'm a bit confused. can you give me an example of how it works here? i fear the rest of my program doesnt follow suit if that's the case.

Comment: You can think of the array as the same as the dot, but it dereferences the pointer first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static const double DAILY_FINE = 0.1` in your cpp file makes sense. Or `static constexpr double DAILY_FINE = 0.1` if you have C++11.

A couple of other comments:

- `for (i=0; i < members.size(); i++)` could be `for (int i = 0; ...`, and then you wouldn't have to declare `i` outside the loop.
- `if (!checkedOut.empty())` followed by the loop over all the contents of `checkedOut` is redundant; if `checkedOut` is empty the loop will never be entered.
- Instead of `for (int x=0; ...`, you can use an iterator: `for (auto x = checkedOut.cbegin(); x != checkedOut.cend(); ++x) {`, and then you can access the elements of the vector like so: `(*x)->getDateCheckedOut()`. If you don't have C++11, `for (std::vector<Book*>::const_iterator x = checkedOut.begin(); x != checkedOut.end(); ++x) {` will do the same thing.
- The number of days it takes for a fine to be assessed (21) should be a constant as well.

Comment: Ah this makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much james.

Comment: @inkling123 You should select this as the answer if it solved your problem.